# JQM PageShow Event makes the screen flash when loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, pageload

The app i'm making has a listview, when a listview item is clicked it opens a new page which displays some info.

When I initially click a listview item, the page opens properly with no problems. When I click the back button and click another listview item the page loads but with no JQM styling at all.

I managed to fix the problem above with the code below but now the page loads for the second time showing the unstyled page, the screen flashes and it loads properly. How do I get the same end result without having the screen reload on the pageshow event.

The code that reloads the page:

```
$("#moduleinfo").live('pageshow', function() {
    $('#infoPara').trigger("create");
});
```

The code that creates the page depending on which listview item is clicked

```
var output = "Module Code: " + results.rows.item(0).module +
    "<br/>Room No: " + results.rows.item(0).room +
    "<br/>URL:" + results.rows.item(0).url + 
    "<b/r><a href='#' data-role='button' data-theme='d' onclick='openURL(\"" 
    + results.rows.item(0).url + "\")'>Open URL</a>" +
    "</br><a href='#' data-role='button'  onclick='deleteEntry(\"" 
    + results.rows.item(0).id + "\")'>Delete Entry</a>";


$('#infoPara').html(output);
$.mobile.changePage( "index.html#moduleinfo", { transition: "slide"} );
```

The page HTML

```
<div data-role="primary-content" id="modinfo">
    <p id="infoPara"></p>
</div>
```

Pretty sure my problem is related to this question:
[How to get jQuery mobile magic to work in "pageshow" event handler? (JQM 1.1.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168889/how-to-get-jquery-mobile-magic-to-work-in-pageshow-event-handler-jqm-1-1-0?answertab=active#tab-top)

Thanks!